# CSS hover is not working with adjacent selector in chrome if the display property set none before

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hover

I have 3 Divs  "**button**","**enableButton**" and a "**tooltip**" in my page. I have set **display:none** for the "button" by default.

The **display** property of "**button**" will change to **block** on clicking the "**enableButton**" div. 
I have some CSS definition that making the tooltip div's display block on mouse over the button. I used adjacent selector (+) with :hover pseudo selector to make the adjacent "tooltip" div visible.

My problems is the tooltip is not showing on mouse over the button in **chrome**. It is working correctly in firefox. Can anybody help on this?. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="enableButton">Click to Enable Button</div>
<br/>

<div  style="display:none;" id="button">Button</div>
<div class="tooltip">this is the tooltip</div>
```

CSS:

```
#enableButton{cursor:pointer; color:red;}
.tooltip{display:none; padding:5px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#button{cursor:pointer;}
#button:hover+.tooltip{display:block;}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#enableButton").click(function(){
    $("#button").show();    
});
```

The code is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gUtt/1/)

*Click the **Click to Enable Button** to make the button visible first and mouse over the button to get the issue*

On firefox the tooltip is showing correctly

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I dont have an explanation, but I do have a fix.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/3gUtt/3/)

Add the CSS:

```
#button {
    cursor:pointer;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#button.enabled {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Then change your jQuery to:

```
$("#enableButton").click(function () {
    $("#button").toggleClass('enabled');
});
```

Setting:

```
    height:0;
    width:0;
    overflow:hidden;
```

Mimics the effect of `display:none;` which seems to be causing the issue in Chrome. The `enabled` class then resets these to their default values, causing the button to show when the class is applied.

Comment: Thanks buddy, This worked...however I am looking for a solution with display:none.